# clearValidators() is working fine with FormControl but does not working with FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to clear and set validator at run time or dynamically.
This is a sample snippet of my formGroup.

```
this.form = fb.group(
{
   details: fb.group(control1, control2, ...),
   address: fb.group(...)
)
```

Case 1 : When I perform clearValidators() on FormControl. Its working as expected.

```
 this.form.get('details.control1').clearValidators();
```

Case 2: When I perform clearValidators() on FormGroup, it is not working.

```
this.form.get('details').clearValidators();
```

Since both formcontrol and FormGroup inherit AbstractControl, clearValidators should be working on FormGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.form.get('details').clearValidatros(), clean the validator of **details**, not the validators of form.get('details.control1),form.get('details.control2)...

Imagine some like

```
form=new FormGroup(
  {
  control:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  control:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  },{ validators: identityRevealedValidator })
```

The clear validator, clean "identityRevailedValidator"

Comment: Great. Thank you. Can you provide any official documentation for this? @Eliseo

Comment: I deduced it from the docs, and for me is logic. It's the same case: the validators are applied to a FormControl or to a FormGroup and are independent each to other. The only consecuence is that if a FormControl is invalid, the FormGroup that containt it  is invalid, but it's the only conexion

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Form

```
this.form.get("xxxx").setErrors(null);
```

Validator

```
control.parent.get("xxx").setErrors(null);
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  Thanks for posting this, but all posts to stack overflow are requested to be in English.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/) for details.  I went ahead and translated the single sentence.